# Is it possible to initialise object fields directly as __init__ keyword parameters?

Tags: python, class

When I write a class, I often do this:

```
class Bulbasaur:
  """Quite obviously, the best pokemon"""
  self __init__(self, n_potions = 0, berries = 0, nickname = '')
    self.n_potions = n_potions
    self.berries = berries
    self.nickname = nickname
```

Perhaps there are other ways to handle the following - if so please
provide (!) - but it seems simpler to do this:

```
class Bulbasaur:
  """Quite obviously, the best pokemon"""
  self __init__(self, self.n_potions = 0, self.berries = 0, self.nickname = '')
    pass
```

Where the fields will be populated with the correct values directly from the
`__init__` arguments. 
Is this possible? If not, what is its design flaw? If not, is there
a better way to handle the aforementioned scenario?

Comment: Does `dataclass` https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html help? This is a new feature in Python 3.7.

Comment: The flaw is that function parameters have to be variable names. `self.n_potions` isn't a variable, it's an object attribute.

Comment: What's wrong with initialising the attributes in the init body?

Comment: This too https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs!

Answer (score 2):

This was an intentional design decision in Python: there is no special syntax for defining the attributes an instance should have or for initializing an object once created. `__init__` is simply another method, albeit one that is called during the process of instantiating a class.

Dataclasses, introduced in Python 3.7, provide a way to reduce some of the boilerplate. Annotated variables in the body of the class statement are used to define a default implementation of `__init__` (among other special methods) that does what you commonly want, which is just to set attributes based on arguments to `__init__`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Bulbasaur:
    n_potions: int = 0
    berries: int = 0
    nickname: str = ''


b1 = Bulbasaur()
assert b1.n_potions == 0 and b1.berries == 0 and b1.nickname == ''
b2 = Bulbasaur(3, 2, 'foo')
assert b2.n_potions == 3 and b2.berries == 2 and b2.nickname == 'foo'
```